# Get the parent name of children's route Vue js

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have this route that has a children. I can retrieve the name of the route however it is only applicable to the name of the children.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home', // <--- I want to get this route name
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('src/pages/Home/Index.vue') },
      { path: '/patient', component: () => import('src/pages/Home/Patient.vue') },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/auth',
    name: 'Auth', <--- I want to get this route name
    component: () => import('layouts/AuthLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/Login.vue') },
      //{ path: '', component: () => import('pages/Login.vue') }
    ]
  },

  // Always leave this as last one,
  // but you can also remove it
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue')
  }
]

export default routes
```

Then I tried remove all named routes from the children and assigned a name to the parent but it gives me
`undefined` whenever I `console.log($route.name)` on the `MainLayout.vue`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is really the right way of getting the parent's route name but I have achieved it using `route.matched`

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
...

const path = computed(() => $route.matched[0].name ) //[0] first one
```

This should return the component name `Home`

Comment: `$route.matched[0]` is the FIRST match in the route's matches. If you have more than one level deep, this won't work. OP needs the second to last one in the matched array. See answer below

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the immediate parent of the current active route .. yes?

In that case, you do as previously mentioned use `this.$route.matched`, but not as stated. The current route is the last item in `$route.matched array`, so to get the immediate parent you can use:

```js
const parent = this.$route.matched[this.$route.matched.length - 2]
const { name, params, query } = parent
this.$router.push({ name, params, query })
```

Answer (score 0):

In my `vue.js 3` project I am using [vite-plugin-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-pages) and for some reason @Shulz's solution gives me `route.matched[0].name: undefined`. So, doing things as mentioned below helped:

In `<template>`

```
<router-link to='/the-page' :class='{ "active": subIsActive("/the-page") }'> The Page </router-link>
```

In `<script>`

```
const subIsActive = (input) => {
  const paths = Array.isArray(input) ? input : [input];
  return paths.some((path) => route.path.indexOf(path) === 0);
};
```

but, as I am using `vite-plugin-pages` I found another solution and I  followed [this](https://github.com/hannoeru/vite-plugin-pages#nested-routes) approach to fix my issue.